# Android- No such column error

Tags: java, android, database, android-fragments, cursor

Error is popping up for me where its telling me a column of mine does not exist. This column exists within my Contract class for my database but for some reason isn't recognized by the cursor.

LOGCAT

```
03-16 16:37:29.029 8240-8240/com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: TEAM_NUMBER
03-16 16:37:29.030 8240-8240/com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-16 16:37:29.030 8240-8240/com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout, PID: 8240
                                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TEAM_NUMBER (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT TEAM_NUMBER, PORTCULLIS, CHEVAL_DE_FRISE, MOAT, RAMPARTS, DRAWBRIDGE, SALLY_PORT, ROCK_WALL, ROCK_TERRAIN, LOW_BAR FROM scout_table
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                                                                                                 at com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout.DatabaseHelper.getInformation(DatabaseHelper.java:63)
                                                                                                 at com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout.ScoutFragment.onCreateView(ScoutFragment.java:40)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Scout.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_NUMBER +
            " INTEGER," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_PORTCULLIS + " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_CHEVAL_FRISE + " TEXT," +
            DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_MOAT + " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_RAMPARTS + " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_DRAWBRIDGE +
            " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_SALLY_PORT + " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_WALL + " TEXT," +
            DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_TERRAIN + " TEXT," + DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_LOW_BAR + " TEXT);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Database created / opened ...");
    } //End of DatabaseHelper

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Create Query
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

        //Display Log message
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "Table created...");
    } //End of onCreate

    public void addInformation(String eNumber, String ePoticullis, String eChevalFrise, String eMoat, String eRamparts, String eDrawbridge, String eSallyPort,
                               String eRockWall, String eRockTerrain, String eLowBar, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Instantiate contentValues
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        //Insert all content values
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_NUMBER, eNumber);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_PORTCULLIS, ePoticullis);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_CHEVAL_FRISE, eChevalFrise);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_MOAT, eMoat);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_RAMPARTS, eRamparts);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_DRAWBRIDGE, eDrawbridge);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_SALLY_PORT, eSallyPort);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_WALL, eRockWall);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_TERRAIN, eRockTerrain);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_LOW_BAR, eLowBar);

        //Insert content values into table
        db.insert(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //Display log message
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS", "One row inserted...");
    } //End of addInformation

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_NUMBER, DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_PORTCULLIS,
                DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_CHEVAL_FRISE, DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_MOAT,DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_RAMPARTS,
                DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_DRAWBRIDGE, DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_SALLY_PORT, DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_WALL,
                DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_ROCK_TERRAIN, DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.COL_LOW_BAR};
        cursor = db.query(DatabaseContract.NewDataInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    } //End of getInformation

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    } //End of onUpgrade
} //End of class
```

ScoutFragment.java

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ScoutFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton addDataScout;
    ListView eListScoutInfo;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListScoutInfoAdapter listScoutInfoAdapter;

    public ScoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    } //End of ScoutFragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, null, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        eListScoutInfo = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listScoutInfo);
        listScoutInfoAdapter = new ListScoutInfoAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        eListScoutInfo.setAdapter(listScoutInfoAdapter);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = databaseHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        //Checks if information is available in cursor
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                //Delcare all strings
                String teamNumber, portcullis, chevalFrise, moat, ramparts, drawbridge, sallyPort, rockWall, rockTerrain, lowBar;

                //Get strings from cursor
                teamNumber = cursor.getString(0);
                portcullis = cursor.getString(1);
                chevalFrise = cursor.getString(2);
                moat = cursor.getString(3);
                ramparts = cursor.getString(4);
                drawbridge = cursor.getString(5);
                sallyPort = cursor.getString(6);
                rockWall = cursor.getString(7);
                rockTerrain = cursor.getString(8);
                lowBar = cursor.getString(9);

                //Get methods from DatabaseProvider
                DatabaseProvider databaseProvider = new DatabaseProvider(teamNumber, portcullis, chevalFrise, moat, ramparts,
                        drawbridge, sallyPort, rockWall, rockTerrain, lowBar);

                //Pass objects to add method
                listScoutInfoAdapter.add(databaseProvider);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } //End of if statement

        //Setups Floating Action Button
        addDataScout = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        addDataScout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddScoutDataFragment fragment = new AddScoutDataFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } //End of onClick
        }); //End of setOnClickListener
        return view;
    } //End of onCreateView
} //End of class
```

DatabaseContract.java

```
public class DatabaseContract {
    public static abstract class NewDataInfo {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "scout_table";
        public static final String COL_NUMBER = "TEAM_NUMBER";
        public static final String COL_PORTCULLIS = "PORTCULLIS";
        public static final String COL_CHEVAL_FRISE = "CHEVAL_DE_FRISE";
        public static final String COL_MOAT = "MOAT";
        public static final String COL_RAMPARTS = "RAMPARTS";
        public static final String COL_DRAWBRIDGE = "DRAWBRIDGE";
        public static final String COL_SALLY_PORT = "SALLY_PORT";
        public static final String COL_ROCK_WALL = "ROCK_WALL";
        public static final String COL_ROCK_TERRAIN = "ROCK_TERRAIN";
        public static final String COL_LOW_BAR = "LOW_BAR";
    } //End of NewDataInfo
} //End of class
```

Comment: Have you created in the first version of the database ?

Comment: Yes, I have created it in the first version `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;`

Comment: I think it would be better if you get the columns with the name like `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract .NewDataInfo .COL_NUMBER ))` for all of them

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you point out to me where it should go?

Comment: Replace `teamNumber = cursor.getString(0);` with the one in my last comment and replace it for all of other columns

Comment: Should I change anything else because I still get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106509/discussion-between-samer-alabi-and-ali-helmy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed you should clear the app data if it still in development as you created the database before without this column, if it in the production phase you should do such upgrades in `OnUpgrad` method.